# How can I track the completion of all tasks of a particular group in the queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

At the moment I'm making a functionality that performs distribution of messages to users. I chose RabbitMQ as the queue server (I use it through Symfony Messenger).

The problem is that each distribution must have a status of PROGRESS and FINISHED. When I start the delivery process and create messages in the queue, the status of the distribution changes to PROGRESS. But I don't understand how to track when the mailing is complete to change the status to FINISHED.

Somehow I have to catch an event when there are no more tasks in the queue for a distribution with a certain ID. What patterns do you know to implement this functionality?

If this is not possible with RabbitMQ can you suggest other message brokers that will allow it?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: You either need to add a database to keep the state of distributions. Or use an orchestrator that provides state tracking out of the box. See for example temporal.io one.